# spring-data-neo4j ChainedTransactionManager causes javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException

Tags: hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

I have a project that uses spring-data-neo4j and spring data with Hibernate. Different entities are persisted with Neo4j and Hibernate, so spring-data-neo4j-cross-store is not required.

I am trying to use the **org.springframework.data.transaction.ChainedTransactionManager** class as my transaction manager, but whenever I try to use a transaction for Hibernate, I get a **javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException**.

Relevant applicationContext.xml:

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:spring-configured/>
<context:component-scan base-package="my.package" />

<bean id="entityManagerFactoryJpa"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="my-persistence-unit-jpa" />
</bean>

<bean id="jpaTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactoryJpa"/>
</bean>
<bean id="jtaTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.JtaTransactionManagerFactoryBean">
    <constructor-arg ref="graphDatabaseService"/>
</bean>
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.data.transaction.ChainedTransactionManager">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <ref bean="jpaTransactionManager"/>
            <ref bean="jtaTransactionManager"/>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<neo4j:repositories base-package="my.package" />
<neo4j:config base-package="my.package" graphDatabaseService="graphDatabaseService" />

<bean id="graphDatabaseService"
    class="org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.GraphDatabaseServiceFactoryBean"
    destroy-method="shutdown" scope="singleton">
    <constructor-arg value="target/graph.db" />
    <constructor-arg>
        <map>
            <entry key="enable_remote_shell" value="false" />
        </map>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

Whenever any Hibernate transaction tries to execute, I get this error:

> javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in
>   progress

How can I use spring-data-neo4j with other Spring projects without these transaction errors?

Answer (score 0):

To get my project to work without errors, I had to change the name of the ChainedTransactionManager bean.

Relevant applicationContext.xml:

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:spring-configured/>
<context:component-scan base-package="my.package" />

<bean id="entityManagerFactoryJpa"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="my-persistence-unit-jpa" />
</bean>

<bean id="jpaTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactoryJpa"/>
</bean>
<bean id="jtaTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.JtaTransactionManagerFactoryBean">
    <constructor-arg ref="graphDatabaseService"/>
</bean>
<bean id="chainedTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.data.transaction.ChainedTransactionManager">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <ref bean="jpaTransactionManager"/>
            <ref bean="jtaTransactionManager"/>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<neo4j:repositories base-package="my.package" />
<neo4j:config base-package="my.package" graphDatabaseService="graphDatabaseService" />

<bean id="graphDatabaseService"
    class="org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.GraphDatabaseServiceFactoryBean"
    destroy-method="shutdown" scope="singleton">
    <constructor-arg value="target/graph.db" />
    <constructor-arg>
        <map>
            <entry key="enable_remote_shell" value="false" />
        </map>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="chainedTransactionManager" />
```

Once I made this change, my project started working as expected. Apparently, Spring automatically creates transaction managers named "transactionManager" in the background, so if you name a ChainedTransactionManager "transactionManager" you get some sort of conflict and Spring doesn't know which transaction manager to use for the transactions.